# How to get the debugging information(line number and column) by using OCaml interface of LLVM?

Tags: debugging, location, ocaml, llvm

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the debugging information from bitcode file, using the OCaml interface of LLVM.

I use `clang` with the parameters `-O0 -g` to get the debugging information in the output bitcode file. The compilation command is like: `clang -c -emit-llvm -O0 -g hello.c`

And, here is my function to get the debugging information from an instruction:

```
let visit_instruction inst =
  let llctx = Llvm.global_context () in
  let md_dbg = Llvm.metadata inst (Llvm.mdkind_id llctx "dbg") in
  match md_dbg with
  | None -> ()
  | Some dbg ->
      print_endline("dbg: " ^ (Llvm.string_of_llvalue dbg));
      let num_oprs = Llvm.num_operands dbg in
      print_endline("dbg num operands: " ^ (string_of_int num_oprs));
      let opr0 = Llvm.operand dbg 0 in
      print_endline("dbg oprand 0: " ^ (Llvm.string_of_llvalue opr0));
      ()
```

Here is an output printed by `print_endline("dbg: " ^ (Llvm.string_of_llvalue dbg));`

> dbg: <0x14c29d8> = !DILocation(line: 10, column: 9, scope: <0x14bf3f0>)

Here is an output printed by the last two printing statements. This output corresponds to the operand `scope: <0x14bf3f0>` of `DILocation`.

> dbg num operands: 1
>
> dbg oprand 0: <0x14bf3f0> = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "main", scope:
>   <0x14ba398>, file: <0x14ba398>, line: 5, type: <0x14bf160>, isLocal: false, isDefinition: true, scopeLine: 5, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, isOptimized: false, unit: <0x14bf478>, variables: <0x14ba8b0>)

Since the number of operands printed is `1`, somehow the first two parameters (`line` and `column`) of `!DILocation(line: 10, column: 9, scope: <0x14bf3f0>)` cannot be accessed.

Is there a **programmatical** way to get the line and column from the debugging inforamation, using the OCaml binding of LLVM? I have working on this issue a few days but could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: As pointed out in a now deleted link-only answer, this can now apparently be accomplished with the newly added [OCaml debuginfo interface](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/bindings/ocaml/debuginfo/llvm_debuginfo.mli)